Access Named Credentials from Site Guest User
I'm trying to assign access to a Named Credential to a site guest user.
I've done some searching and found two different set of steps to do this put neither of them works.
First I tried to create a Permission Set that had access to the User External Credentials object but if I do that I get an error when trying to assign the guest user to the Permission Set.
The other thing I tried was to update the Profile of the guest user to enable External Credentials Access. I did that. I also tried to enable Named Credential Access but the named credential doesn't show up.
When I try to use the named credential as the guest user I get the following error:
System.CalloutException: The callout couldn't access the endpoint. You might not have the required permissions, or the named credential \"Test_NamedCred\" might not exist.\n\nClass.myClass.myEvent: line 18, column 1
I found this https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_security_named_credentials_guestuser.htm&release=246&type=5
but when I try to do that I can't find User External Credentials as an option.
I don't know what I'm missing.

N.B. Control Who Can Perform Authenticated Callouts with Ease. You should just need to assign R CRUD access on UserExternalCredential to the PS assigned to Guest User
